# Armature rest matrix - why does this exist?

Tags: python, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, blender

i thought that the rest pose matrix of all the joints in the 3d model(b3d etc) should have the rotation values 0, but when i loaded the 3d model using opengl in my ios device , it displays different rotation values for the joints initially.

how does this happens ? should't the rotation values be 0 for rest pose ? or is there any other way to find the rest pose matrix calculation ?

Edit: does the roll,head,tail values(blender) of joints of the rest pose determines the rotation values of the joints ?

Comment: Good question. I suggest you hop over to the FreeNode IRC #blender-dev channel. 'kaito' (=Ton Rosendaal) will be able to explain that.

Comment: sorry i could't understand your comment. can you explain it briefly ?

Comment: FreeNode is an IRC network. IRC is a chat system. `#blender-dev` is a chatroom in the FreeNode network, where Blender developers are active. and *kaito* is the nickname of Ton Rosendaal, the original developer of Blender.